# Can I use EFCore's DBContextPool with .NET Core Console Application

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

`services.AddDbContextPool` is the suggested practice of adding connection pool for EF Core. However, seems that this practice is only suitable for .NET MVC/Web API, etc. framework. What if I want to use it with Console Application which does not come with a `Startup` point? Is there any way to achieve what connection pool does without using it with `MS.DI`? Or what should I do to achieve that by other 3rd parties DI framework? e.g. Autofac, Ninject, Unity, etc.